# Complex conjugation inducing a trivial map on the fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology, fundamental-group

Let $V$ be a smooth projective complex variety defined over the reals such that $G=\pi_1(V)$ is a non-abelian finite simple group. Assume that $V$ has a real point. Can the map $G\to G$ induced by complex conjugation be trivial?

Comment: How does conjugation act on $V$ or $G$?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I forgot to add a condition

Comment: Don't forget about base points. Usually it can be ignored, but in this case, you probably need to pick one in $V(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, the set of real points should be nonempty.

Comment: You might be able to concoct an example from a finite group representation. Suppose one has a complex representation which is conjugation equivariant, so that conjugation acts nontrivially. The action on a Flag variety should give a complex projective variety with the appropriate properties I think.

Comment: Where are going to get variety over $\mathbb C$ with fundamental group $G$? Have you heard of Godeaux-Serre varieties? I think that if you just follow the construction over $\mathbb R$, you get what you seek. I googled Godeaux-Serre to see if there was a useful reference, and I didn't find one. But I did find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01835) saying that you can have whatever action you want, over any field.

Comment: @vrz why did you delete another question of yours after I answered it in the comments?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I thought it was not research-level